# how do I define/save java.util.Calendar in Postgres SQL (JPA using liquibase)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, liquibase

I am trying to figure out how to define a `Calendar` object in JPA so that I can save it in the Postgres DB..  I know how to save a `dt` or `datetime` entity to the DB, but I am not understanding how to save a `Calendar` object.

Here is my entity definition

```java
....

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "User", schema = "Auth")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "UserId")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "Mail")
    private String mail;

    @Column(name = "CalendarEntry")
    private Calendar calendarEntry;

}
```

And this is my Liquibase db/migration file for the SQL definition..

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Auth.User
(
    UserId                      SERIAL,
    Mail                        VARCHAR(256),
    CalendarEntry               TIMESTAMP(2) NULL,
    );
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_user_mail ON Auth.User (Mail);
```

Notice that I have a regular `TIMESTAMP` definition as the SQL type for the `CalendarEntry` column. I want to know what I should substitute for `Calendar` in that SQL column definition.

I am new to JPA (and Java in general) so this is confusing me. thanks for any help ...

Comment: Don't. Use the [`java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) instead.

Comment: The terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, and `Timestamp` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Search to learn more. Saving date-time values in Java to a database has been addressed many many times already.

Comment: You are using the wrong type for your database column. Use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not WITHOUT, to record moments, specific points on the timeline. Search to learn more. This has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow.